# Convert a coordinate of J2000 to current date?

Tags: astronomy

I am using the VSOP2000 data files and were able to calculate the cartesian coordinate of the sun and the moon at time T... The question is how to convert that coordinate (which in the time frame of J2000) to current date (time T)? I just like to know the algorithm.

Comment: OK.. I finally found the answer. The rotation matrix is found in the VSOP87 paper. Since both VSOP87 and VSOP2000 are from the same "system", the matrix is good enough applied to VSOP2000 data. Of course, I could use the VSOP87 data instead, but only VSOP2000 has the moon data that I need.

Comment: Huy, can you point me at the VSOP2000 algorithm? I'd like to update my VSOP87 implementation if possible. I can only find a paper that's behind a paywall.

Comment: Here is the link: ftp://syrte.obspm.fr/francou/vsop2000/

Comment: Tim, was that link helping you? You can find the algorithm in the included Fortran code.. I can further elaborate if you need it...

Comment: Thanks @Huy-Pham - I was hoping to find the paper. I found the paper very helpful when doing VSOP87. I haven't had a chance to work on this yet, too many other projects!

Comment: You mean the paper on the VSOP87 algorithm? I too have that paper...

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things you might consider.

1. You can use the [ASCOM Platform](http://ascom-standards.org) to convert coordinates from JNow (local topocentric) to J2000 astrometric, using the `Transform` class.
2. If you don't want to take a dependency on ASCOM, then you can get it's source code from SourceForge and you'll see that it uses the [IAU's SOFA library](http://www.iausofa.org/) (Standards of Fundamental Astronomy). There is a C# port of the SOFA library called World Wide Astronomy, but it is a bit buggy.
3. You might also look at [AASharp](https://github.com/jsauve/AASharp), a port of the C version of Astronomical Algorithms

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions... the ASCOM and SOFA are too big for my project... and the AASharp is based on the C++ version of AA+ which I already have...

Comment: Sofa library is not really very big at all.  So is this correct Sofa ICRS is J2000, and CIRS is JNow ?

Answer (score 0):

J2000 is just JD2451545.0 ([ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28astronomy%29#Julian_years_and_J2000)), so you can just convert J2000 to JD and follow an algorithm to get Gregorian date from JD. Here is some python code to do just that, based on *Astronomical Algorithms* Chapter 7.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class J2000:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def to_JD(self):
        return self.value + 2451545.0

    def to_datetime(self):
        jd = self.to_JD()
        # based on AA Ch7
        z = int(jd + 0.5)
        f = jd + 0.5 - z 
        alpha = int((z - 1867216.25) / 36524.25)
        a = z + 1 + alpha - int(alpha / 4)
        b = a + 1524
        c = int((b - 122.1) / 365.25)
        d = int(365.25 * c)
        e = int((b - d) / 30.6001)
        day = b - d - int(30.6001 * e) + f
        d = int(day) # day
        d_frac = day - d # fractional day
        m = e - 1 if e < 14 else e - 13 # month
        y = c - 4716 if m > 2 else c - 4715 # year
        return datetime(y, m, d) + timedelta(days=d_frac)
```

For example:

```
j = J2000(2456647 - 2451545) # J2000 for 12/20/13 12:00:00
j.to_datetime()
=> datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 20, 12, 0)
```

Comment: I don't know python... but if I am not mistaken, the above code just give me the time elapsed since J2000, correct? What I need is epoch conversion of coordinates. I think it is called precession.